# Identifying a component symbol in a schematic

Tags: operational-amplifier, components, schematics, reverse-engineering

**Problem:** So I have ran across the following part and I simply don't know what it is. I tried searching for if you will a description of it. (I.E. two diodes on top of each other pointing opposite directions) This of course did not help.

**Help:** So what is this?
[image: idk]

**Advice:** So when you run across something you don't know how do you solve this? I mean besides using context clues from the circuit. If its just a symbol and you can not identify the part. Advice?

**Notes:** It is from the block diagram of the datasheet of the [MC14468](http://www.freescale.com/files/analog/doc/data_sheet/MC14468.pdf).

Comment: Can you say a bit about the context of the symbol? Was it in an analog circuit or a digital circuit? Was there a reference designator (U1, IC3, etc.)? Was there a part number associated with it?

Comment: Google image search lets you drop an image to search for visually similar things. Sometimes that's helpful, but in this case it looks like [that component is a chair](http://bit.ly/1qY5Tcb).

Comment: It is from the block diagram of the datasheet of the MC14468. Link - http://www.freescale.com/files/analog/doc/data_sheet/MC14468.pdf

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I guess thank you! Im also curious how to solve this question going forward though. In the end I am not sure how I would have found that answer. I do not view it as 4 triangles and rather 2 diodes. Thanks though!

Comment: The only advice I can provide is to find a diagram with a large number of symbols and look hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember seeing a similar question here (but couldn't find it). The component seems to be a transmission gate, or analog switch. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate)

Google-ing it helps you find the schematic: https://www.google.hu/search?q=transmission+gate+symbol